# Normalization bug?

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I am trying to normalize and denormalize data to and from `[-1, 1]`.

For normalization, I have:

```
def normalize(X, min_value, max_value):
  return 2*((X - min_value)/(max_value - min_value)) - 1
```

where X is a numpy vector.

For denormalization, I wrote out the formula and solved for the inverse to get:

```
def denormalize(X, min_value, max_value):
  return ((max_value-min_value)*((X-1)/2)) + min_value
```

If I do this:

```
import numpy as np
n = normalize(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 1, 4)
```

I correctly get `[-1 -0.33333333  0.33333333  1.]`

However, if I do `denormalize(n, 1, 4)`, I don't get the original array back.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `X+1` in `denormalize`, not `X-1`:

```
def denormalize(X, min_value, max_value):
  return ((max_value-min_value)*((X+1)/2)) + min_value 

denormalize(n, 1, 4)
# array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```